# Split an array into a MD array every nth line

Tags: php, arrays

bit of a question here. Ive got an array that contains data which has been parsed from a website using all our favourite php functions such as array_map.

The array is current 3 sub arrays deep.

Here is the code I am using:

```
for ($tcid = 1; $tcid <= count($categories); $tcid++) {
    $catHeader[$tcid] = $categories[$tcid][0];
    $event[$i]['tickets'] = $categories;

    unset($categories[$tcid][0]);

    $categories[$tcid] = array_map('trim', $categories[$tcid]);
    $categories[$tcid] = array_values($categories[$tcid]);
    $ab = 0;
    for ($b = 0; $b <= count($categories[$tcid]); $b++) {
        if ($categories[$tcid][$b] == "" || !$categories[$tcid][$b] || $categories[$tcid][$b] == null) {
            unset($categories[$tcid][$b]);
        }
    }
}
```

and the array looks something like....

```
[1] => Array (

    [data] => Array ( ...
        )
    [tickets] => Array (
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => xxx
            [1] => etc
            [3] => etc2
            )
        [2] => (
            [0] => Std1
            [1] => 10 / 10
            [2] => &pound;20.00
            [3] => &pound;200.00
            [4] => Std2
            [5] => 100 / 100 
            [6] => &pound;13.00
            [7] => &pound;1,300.00
            [8] => Std3
            [9] => 10 / 320
            [10] => &pound;15.00
            [11] => &pound;150.00
        )
    )
)
```

My question to you today, is how on earth do I split the array every 4 \n's or array keys as they're known and explode each 4 into a further sub array?

So that Std1, Std2, Std3 will be their own sub array with its associated data of the 2nd key of tickets, but also doing this for every sub array of tickets that has more than 1 set of data (a set of data being 4 array keys).

I've tried all sorts but can't get it to work.

See below of how I want it to look.

```
[1] => Array (

        [data] => Array ( ...
            )
        [tickets] => Array (
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => xxx
                [1] => etc
                [3] => etc2
                )
            [2] => (
                [0] => Array (
                    [0] => Std1
                    [1] => 10 / 10
                    [2] => &pound;20.00
                    [3] => &pound;200.00
                 )
                [1] => Array (
                    [0] => Std2
                    [1] => 100 / 100 
                    [2] => &pound;13.00
                    [3] => &pound;1,300.00
                )
                [2] => Array (
                    [0] => Std3
                    [1] => 10 / 320
                    [2] => &pound;15.00
                    [3] => &pound;150.00
                )

            )
        )
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post what you expect the final array to look like

Comment: If it's always going to be `4`, couldn't you just `array_chunk()` it?

Comment: @nogad, done.

@Darren i've tried that but instead of doing what I want it just pushes the array within the ticket key into another sub array - 

`    [tickets] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (` like so

Comment: You could handle it by-reference somewhere within your loop (*Take the following for example: `$array['tickets'][2] = array_chunk($array['tickets'][2], 4);`*) -> [**Example/Demo**](https://www.tehplayground.com/lCuSo6uxmKLZZ7Yk). Generates it as you require.

Comment: @Darren You are absolutely right. I'm using `foreach($event[$i]['tickets'] as &$value) {
      $value = array_chunk($value, 4);
     }` and it's now throwing _Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()_ .. except it's actually working

Comment: @DomLip Hrm, could it be that one of your `"event"`'s doesn't have any `ticket` sub-array?

Comment: @Darren again.. you're absolutely right. Will just add error checking now. Thank you, been trying to figure it out for hours!!

Comment: @DomLip That's alright man :) sometimes you just need different eyes looking at it! (*and 10 cups of coffee ;-)*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you'd be best off handling your array by-reference to modify it's original contents somewhere within your loops

Provided the array groupings you want to chunk are in groups of `4`, you could [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk) it:

```
$array['tickets'][2] = array_chunk($array['tickets'][2], 4);
```